# Looping Through a Group in Suitescript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am passing sales orders grouped by item into a function. I need to load the sales orders to modify the sales order record that it has already been processed. How would I go about getting all sales orders grouped under the item?

```
var itemId = result.getValue({
                name: 'item',
                summary: 'GROUP'
            });
```

The above code gets me the item id for what the orders in the given result are being grouped by. There could be any number of sales within a single group.

Answer (score 1):

Running a grouped saved search in SuiteScript doesn't give you the ability to "drill down" like you can when running a similar search in the user interface. As soon as you have a summary criteria for any column in a saved search, Netsuite requires that all your columns be summarized. If you want to get the internal IDs for the Sales Orders, then they will have to be returned as a summarized column in your saved search code.

Something like this:

```js
const searchObj = search.create({
  type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  filters: [
    ['mainline', 'is', 'F']
    //,'AND', any other filters you need...
  ],
  columns: [
    search.createColumn({
      name: "item",
      summary: "GROUP"
    }),
    search.createColumn({
      name: "formula(text)",
      summary: "MAX",
      formula: "ns_concat({internalid})"
    })
  ]
}).run().each(function(result) {
  const itemId = result.getValue({name: "item", summary: "GROUP"})
  const salesOrderIds = result.getValue({
    name: "formula(text)",
    summary: "MAX",
    formula: "ns_concat({internalid})"
  }).split(',')
  
  return true
})
```